# Accessing a website in python

Tags: python, url, web

I am trying to get all the urls on a website using python. At the moment I am just copying the websites html into the python program and then using code to extract all the urls. Is there a way I could do this straight from the web without having to copy the entire html?

Comment: What library are you using? selenium? splinter? urllib?

Comment: I'm not sure what those mean I'm quite new to programming

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the combination of [**`requests`**](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [**`BeautifulSoup`**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

- First make an `HTTP` request using `requests` to get the HTML content. You will get it as a Python string, which you can manipulate as you like.
- Take the HTML content string and supply it into the `BeautifulSoup`, which has done all the job to extract the `DOM`, and get all URLs, i.e. `<a>` elements.

Here is an example of how to fetch all links from StackOverflow:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

response = requests.get('http://stackoverflow.com')
html_str = response.text

bs = BeautifulSoup(html_str, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a'))

for a_element in bs:
    if a_element.has_attr('href'):
        print(a_element['href'])
```

Sample output:

```
/questions/tagged/facebook-javascript-sdk
/questions/31743507/facebook-app-request-dialog-keep-loading-on-mobile-after-fb-login-called
/users/3545752/user3545752
/questions/31743506/get-nuspec-file-for-existing-nuget-package
/questions/tagged/nuget
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward would probably be `urllib.urlopen` if you're using python2, or `urllib.request.urlopen` if you're using python3 (you have to do `import urllib` or `import urllib.request` first of course). That way you get an file like object from which you can read (ie `f.read()`) the html document.

Example for python 2:

```
import urllib

f = urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com")

http_document = f.read()
f.close()
```

The good news is that you seem to have done the hard part which is analyzing the html document for links.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2, you can use [`urllib2.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#fetching-urls):

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://python.org/')
html = response.read()
```

In Python 3, you can use [`urllib.request.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/urllib2.html#fetching-urls):

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://python.org/') as response:
    html = response.read()
```

If you have to perform more complicated tasks like authentication or passing parameters I suggest to have a look at the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the bs4(BeautifulSoup) library.

Beautiful Soup is a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and XML files.

You can download bs4 with the followig command at the cmd line. `pip install BeautifulSoup4`

```
import urllib2
import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.google.com"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
content = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print urlparse.urljoin(url, link['href'])
```